# I used GET method instead of POST to pass variables. How to fix this?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a large website. I used GET method a lot even when passing lots of variables.
So the url is very lengthy.

The thing is that everything worked fine for a long time. Now suddenly the server is throwing an error

**The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.**

I am trying to figure why this error came about. If I made a mistake of not choosing POST to pass the data, why is it affecting the server now?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're getting to the maximum size of URLs supported by most servers (IIRC 2k or 4k), and the server just aborts the request?

Comment: But it worked well in the past for many months. How did work? and why is it an issue now?

Comment: If you haven't changed your code at all, perhaps a security update broke it? I mean, try reading your server's error logs.

Answer (score 0):

The script probably consumed the maximum execution time, by default its 30 seconds (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).). You can adjust it in `php.ini`, if you have access to it.

Comment: Can you tell if POST method decreases the maximum execution time?